# Why is the setuid permission bit not set for mkdir in modern Unix systems?

Tags: unix, system-calls

**[Bach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132017997)** states the following:

> **mkdir** is a typical `setuid` program. Only a process with Effective UID root can create a folder. (Section 7.6, Page 229)

---

I checked the permissions on it on Ubuntu 12.04, the setuid bit isn't set.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42624 Oct  2 08:55 mkdir
   ^??
```

Then I checked other programs which are supposed to have this set, like `ping` and `su` and they have it set.

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 34740 Nov  8  2011 ping
   ^---there it is
```

So, how does `mkdir` work? Have things changed since Bach wrote that?

Comment: That may be the case, but it isn't a programming question either.

Comment: IIRC, at the time Bach wrote that, there were no separate system calls for directories, open() and read() and write() worked also for directory inodes. With possible diasastrous effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mkdir() call  has been around since BSD 4.2.  It was later added to SYSV 3.0.
See:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html

BSD 4.2 came out in 1984:
http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html

If access to a kernel mode entry point in UNIX via a syscall is permitted from user mode without restriction, what duskwuff indicates, then setuid is not required.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the links, and the timeline. The older version of mkdir.c you have linked doesn't seem to make the `setuid()` system call. Is it definitely the right one?

Comment: That version of mkdir was relatively modern -- it uses `mkdir()`.

Answer (score 3):

It's no longer necessary to have root privileges to create a folder. There's now instead a `mkdir()` system call which any process can use to create a directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Have things changed since Bach wrote that?

Exactly. The permission to create a directory is nowadays based on the write permission to the parent directory or the `t` bit (for /tmp-like directories where everybody can create a directory but you can only delete files owned by you).

Comment: I agree, but this is regarding permissions on the mkdir executable, not the destination folder.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what has changed. The permission check hash moved from checking the mkdir executable's setuid bit to the parent dirs write bit for the effective user.